# Ember.JS : 'serializer.get is not a function'

Tags: serialization

So i'm learning EMBER JS from codeschool and i sometime like to save my current progress into my computer. Everything went nice and smoothly until we started to see Array Controller ( and by nice and smoothly i mean everything was working fine, as it does on codeschool ). Since then i got this error :

```
Error while processing route: index serializer.get is not a function TypeError: serializer.get is not a function
at ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$normalizeResponseHelper (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember-data.js:5696:24)
at http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember-data.js:7450:31
at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:222:25)
at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._adapterRun (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember-data.js:13030:37)
at http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember-data.js:7449:19
at tryCatch (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:54770:14)
at invokeCallback (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:54785:15)
at publish (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:54753:9)
at http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:31568:7
at Queue.invoke (http://localhost:63342/Cours/EmberJS/Flint/js/vendors/ember.js:901:16)
```

So i thought, somehow, my ember.js or ember-data.js was the culprit but nay, it's not ( im up-to-date ). I think the bug is somewhere located in the way i initialize my Route ( eventho i copy/pasted the content of my local files from those on codeschool who works perfectly ) and according to the error message, i think the index route is responsible so here is my router map :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.route('credits', { path: '/thanks' });
this.resource('products', function() {
    this.resource('product', { path: '/:product_id' });
});
this.resource('contacts', function() {
    this.resource('contact', { path: '/:contact_id' });
});
```

});

And here's my route ( they're all made like this one, except that i sometime search in 'contact' rather than 'product' )

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('product');
}
```

});

We also use the fixture adapter so it might come from this too :

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

Does anybody ever got this bug about the serializer ? Thank you'all in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the [removal of the Fixture Adapter](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/05/ember-data-1-0-beta-19-released.html#toc_fixture-adapter-removed) in a recent ember-data release.  I'm just learning ember myself, but I was finally able to get rid of this error using a combination of reverting to a slightly older ember-data version and installing the replacement [Fixture Adapter addon](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter).

In your application dir, update the ember-data line in both bower.json and package.json to:

```
   "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.19.2",
```

and in package.json add this line after the ember-data one:

```
   "ember-data-fixture-adapter": "^1.0.0",
```

Delete the bower_components and node_modules dirs in your application, and then run `npm install` and `bower install` from your application's home dir.